# Container list in Python: standard list vs numpy array

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy

I'm writing some python code that needs to store and access a list of different kinds of elements. Each element of this list will be of a different class type.  For example:

```
def file_len(fname):
    i = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

element_list = [ ]
data = np.loadtxt(filename)


if file_len(filename) == 1 : 
            data = np.loadtxt(filename)
            param1 = data[0]
            param2 = data[1]
            element_list.append(Class1.Class1(param1,param2))
else:
    for field in data:
                    param1 = field[0]
                    param2 = field[1]
                    element_list.append(Class1.Class1(param1, param2)
```

Later I will need to access the methods from Class1 inserted on element_list several times, but the list will not needed to be modified:

```
for i in xrange(10000):
    for element in element_list:
        result += element.calculate_result(i).real #the results will be complex
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your actual problem? and what do you mean by _efficient_?

Comment: I have to access this list a billion times or more, and this is _slow_. One of the bottlenecks is accessing the elements. Is there a more pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: You might be able to speed up the computation by performing operations on the numpy array `data`. By parceling out the data into a **list** of `Class1.Class1` instances, we've lost the opportunity to take advantage of numpy. But to really help you we'd need to see the definition of `calculate_result`.

Comment: This strikes me as potentially a problem in which the layers should be reversed - a class with an array attribute, rather than an array of classes. Is there a reason why you need a class for each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but I spotted two things I could contribute.

Here is an improved version of `file_len()`.  This one will return 0 if the file is zero-length.  Your function returns 1 for a zero-length file, and 1 for a file with one line.

```
def file_len(fname):
    i = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f, 1):
            pass
    return i
```

Here is a faster way to do the compute loop.

```
result = sum(e.calculate_result(i).real for i in xrange(10000) for e in element_list)
```

It might be possible to make it even faster using `reduce()`, but I don't think it can be much faster.  The big savings with `reduce()` is if you can avoid binding names over and over, but we need to bind the name `e` so we can call `e.calculate_result(i).real` even when the type of `e` could be anything.

If you could do something like this it might be a bit faster.

```
import itertools as it
import operator as op
result = reduce(op.add, it.imap(SomeClass.calculate_something, it.product(element_list, xrange(10000))))
```

Again, the main savings is to avoid binding names.  `it.product()` returns tuples that include `(e, i)` where `e` is an element from `element_list` and `i` is a number from `xrange(10000)`.  Then `it.imap()` will call the function and pass the tuple as an argument.  Then `reduce()` will sum everything.  Actually, just calling `sum()` is probably as good as `reduce(op.add)` but you could try it both ways and see if either one is slightly faster than the other.  If you can figure out something sensible for `SomeClass.calculate_something` then maybe you can make this work.

Hmm, it might be worth trying just letting `sum()` (or `reduce()`) compute a complex sum, and then throw away the imaginary part when the sum is done.  Would that be faster than accessing the `.real` attribute once per value?  I'm not sure, but it might help you make the `reduce()` version work.

EDIT:

You should try running your program under PyPy.

http://pypy.org/

If you do that, be sure to use this line instead of the first one I showed:

```
result = sum(e.calculate_result(i).real for e in element_list for i in xrange(10000))
```

This way, you are using each element `e` for 10000 calls in a row, which should help the PyPy just-in-time compiler ("JIT") to produce better code.  I don't know if the JIT will help with only 10000 calls or not, but it seems like that should be the way to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the results inside the class into a view into the array by passing that view at instantiation. If you're accessing the data more often than you're calling class methods to update it, this should work.

Something like the following...

```
def file_len(fname):
    i = 0
    with open(fname) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i + 1

element_list = [ ]
data = np.loadtxt(filename)


array_idx = 0

# length_of_data is the number of elements that will be in element_list
result_array = numpy.zeros(length_of_data, dtype='complex128')

if file_len(filename) == 1 : 
    data = np.loadtxt(filename)
    param1 = data[0]
    param2 = data[1]
    element_list.append(Class1.Class1(param1, param2, 
                            result_array[array_idx:array_idx+1]))
    array_idx += 1
else:
    for field in data:
        param1 = field[0]
        param2 = field[1]
        element_list.append(Class1.Class1(param1, param2,
                            result_array[array_idx:array_idx+1])
        array_idx += 1
```

Inside the class you'd then update the view directly. Consider this minimal example:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.zeros(5, dtype='complex128')

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, real, imag, array_view):
        self._array_view = array_view
        self._array_view[:] = real + 1j*imag #<--- The [:] is needed


element_list = []
for n in range(0, len(a)):
    element_list.append(Foo(n, n+1, a[n:n+1]))

print(a)
print(numpy.sum(a))
```